# Constructing formulas in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Let $\sigma = \{ +, R \}$ be a signature with a binary functional symbol $+$ and a binary relation symbol $R$,  and let  $\mathcal{N}(\mathbb{N}, +^\mathcal{N}, R^\mathcal{N})$ be a $\sigma-$strucutre where $+^\mathcal{N}$ is the normal addition of numbers and $R^\mathcal{N}:= \{ (x,y) \vert x \text{ divides } y \text{ and } x\neq 0\}$. Give for each of the following a formula $\varphi_i$:
>
> $(i)$ $\varphi_1(\mathcal{N}) = \{ 1 \}.$
>
> $(ii)$ $\varphi_2(\mathcal{N})$ is the set of all odd numbers.
>
> $(iii)$ $\varphi_3(\mathcal{N}) = \{ (x, y) \vert gcd(x, y) = 1 \}$ (where gcd is the greatest common divisor)

For $(i)$ I have:

$$\varphi_1(x) = \forall y (R(x, y))$$

Since $R$ guarantees that $x$ cannot be $0$.

For $(ii)$ I have first defined $\varphi_2'$ such that $\varphi_2'(\mathcal{N}) = \{2\}:$

$$\varphi_2'(x):= \exists z (\varphi_1(z) \land x = z + z)$$

Here I'm forcing $z$ to be $1$. (Question: am I allowed to use $y$ instead of $z$ or would that change the meaning of $\varphi_1$?)

I have then defined $\varphi_2''$ such that $\varphi_2''(\mathcal{N})$ is the set of all even numbers:

$$\varphi_2''(x):= \exists y (R(y, x) \land \varphi'_2(y))$$

And finally

$$\varphi_2(x) := \lnot \varphi_2''(x)$$

For $(iii)$:

$$\varphi'_3(x, y) := (\varphi_2''(x) \land \varphi_2(y)) \lor (\varphi_2''(y) \land \varphi_2(x))$$

Here I'm forcing $x$ to be even and $y$ odd or vice-versa. Can someone please check my work?

Answer (score 1):

(i) looks fine, (ii) looks correct but is overly complicated (and I'm not sure I understand your question about $y$) and (iii) is wrong. For (ii) it's enough to say $\varphi_2(x) \equiv \lnot \exists y (x = y + y)$. For (iii) an easy counterexample is that every two prime numbers have a gcd of 1. Maybe remember that if 1 is the gcd of two numbers then it is the $\textit{only}$ number that divides both?